# Not recieving OTP using Firebase Phone Auth - Error:17093

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

Yes, I have added both of my SHA keys(Note: all my debug and release keys are the same) and went over to the docs but still, I am facing the error saying:

```
E/FirebaseAuth(22214): [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17093 null
```

The phone auth was working earlier but now all of a sudden I am getting these logs for every number I enter and request for OTP meaning I am not getting OTP due to this error somehow:

```
W/System  (22214): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
E/zzf     (22214): Failed to get reCAPTCHA token with error [An internal error has occurred. [ Failed to generate/retrieve public encryption key for reCAPTCHA flow. ]]- calling backend without app verification
W/LocalRequestInterceptor(22214): Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: Too many attempts.
W/System  (22214): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
W/LocalRequestInterceptor(22214): Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: Too many attempts.
E/FirebaseAuth(22214): [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17093 null
```

Is this happening because of authentication being added to AppCheck or something else?
Here is my Flutter code which handles the authentication part:

```dart
class LoginScreenState2 extends State<LoginScreen2> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldkey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  String? _verificationCode;
  final TextEditingController _pinPutController = TextEditingController();
  String? uid;
  bool? verified;

  Widget buildPinPut() {
    SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('PinPut.show');

    final defaultPinTheme = PinTheme(
      width: 56,
      height: 60,
      textStyle: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 20, color: Color(0xFFF2F2F2), fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: const Color.fromRGBO(217, 217, 217, 1)),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
    );

    final focusedPinTheme = defaultPinTheme.copyDecorationWith(
      border: Border.all(color: const Color.fromRGBO(114, 178, 238, 1)),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
    );

    final submittedPinTheme = defaultPinTheme.copyWith(
      decoration: defaultPinTheme.decoration?.copyWith(
        color: const Color(0xFF6FB9A0),
      ),
    );

    return Pinput(
      androidSmsAutofillMethod: AndroidSmsAutofillMethod.none,
      defaultPinTheme: defaultPinTheme,
      controller: _pinPutController,
      length: 6,
      focusedPinTheme: focusedPinTheme,
      submittedPinTheme: submittedPinTheme,
      pinputAutovalidateMode: PinputAutovalidateMode.onSubmit,
      showCursor: true,
      onCompleted: (pin) async {
        try {
          PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
              verificationId: _verificationCode!, smsCode: pin);
          await FirebaseAuth.instance
              .signInWithCredential(credential)
              .then((value) async {
            if (value.user != null) {
              uid = value.user!.uid;
              FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('Users')
                  .doc(uid)
                  .get()
                  .then((value) {
                verified = value.data()?['verified'];
                if (verified == true) {
                  Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Home()),
                          (route) => false);
                } else if (verified == false) {
                  Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Verify()),
                          (route) => false);
                } else if (verified == null) {
                  Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const OnBoarding()),
                          (route) => false);
                  FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.delete();
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                      content:
                      Text('You don\'t have an account, So create one')));
                }
              });
            } else {
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                  content: Text('Something went wrong, Create an account')));
            }
          });
        } catch (e) {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
              .showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text('Invalid Code')));
          // ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(e.toString())));
        }
      },
    );
  }

  int _counter = 30;
  late Timer _timer;

  void _startTimer() {
    _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      _counter == 0
          ? cancelTimer()
          : mounted
          ? setState(() {
        _counter--;
      })
          : null;
    });
  }

  void cancelTimer() {
    _timer.cancel();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldkey,
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        extendBodyBehindAppBar: false,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFF2F2F2),
          elevation: 0,
          leading: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.arrow_back_ios_new_rounded,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(),
          child: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0xFFF2F2F2),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, top: 10, right: 24.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 110, bottom: 10),
                        child: Image(
                            image: Image.asset("asset/OTP2.png").image,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .8,
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25),
                      ),
                      const Text(
                        'Verification Code',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'ProductSans',
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Color(0xFF1B1B1B),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 70, right: 70),
                        child: Text(
                          'Please enter Verification code we have sent to your mobile number.',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'ProductSans',
                            fontSize: 15.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                            color: Color(0xFF1B1B1B),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding:
                        const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, left: 70, right: 70),
                        child: Text(
                          '$_counter left',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'ProductSans',
                            fontSize: 15.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                            color: Color(0xFF1B1B1B),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: 30, bottom: 30, left: 20, right: 20),
                        child: buildPinPut(),
                      ),
                      const Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 70, right: 70),
                        child: Text(
                          'Didn\'t receive code?',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'ProductSans',
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                            color: Color(0xFF1B1B1B),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      TextButton(
                        style: ButtonStyle(
                            overlayColor:
                            MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent)),
                        child: const Text(
                          'Resend OTP',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'ProductSans',
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                            color: Color(0xFF6FB9A0),
                          ),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            _counter = 30;
                          });
                          _startTimer();
                          _verifyPhone();
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _verifyPhone() async {
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

    await auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: '+91${widget.phone}',
        verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
          await auth.signInWithCredential(credential).then((value) async {
            if (value.user != null) {
              uid = value.user!.uid;
              FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('Users')
                  .doc(uid)
                  .get()
                  .then((value) {
                verified = value.data()?['verified'];
                if (verified == true) {
                  Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Home()),
                          (route) => false);
                } else if (verified == false) {
                  Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Verify()),
                          (route) => false);
                } else if (verified == null) {
                  Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const OnBoarding()),
                          (route) => false);
                  FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.delete();
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                      content:
                      Text('You don\'t have an account, So create one')));
                }
              });
            } else {
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                  content: Text('Something went wrong, Create an account')));
            }
          });
        },
        verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
          if (e.code == 'invalid-phone-number') {
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                content: Text('The provided phone number is not valid.')));
          }
        },
        codeSent: (String verificationID, int? resendToken) {
          setState(() {
            _verificationCode = verificationID;
          });
        },
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationID) {
          if (mounted) {
            setState(() {
              _verificationCode = verificationID;
            });
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                content: Text('OTP retrieval timed out. Please try again.')));
          }
        },
        timeout: const Duration(seconds: 30));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _verifyPhone();
    _startTimer();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
    _startTimer();
  }
}
```

I am running the Flutter app on debug mode in a OnePlus device (Not sure this will help but I will drop it here anyway):

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsBinding widgetsBinding = WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]);
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
      name: 'OLC', options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
          AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true, badge: true, sound: true);

  FlutterNativeSplash.preserve(widgetsBinding: widgetsBinding);
  FlutterNativeSplash.remove();

  await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
    webRecaptchaSiteKey: _webKey,
    androidProvider: AndroidProvider.debug,
    appleProvider: AppleProvider.appAttest,
  );

  FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);

  // start freeRASP
  await Talsec.instance.start(config);

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

I really appreciate any help you can provide :)

Comment: hi seems `Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: Too many attempts.` you attempt many time. try to change your device and test

Comment: If its already working and if you are in the daily limits . try with some other device

Comment: @mageshmagi Still getting the same error for every device: ```W/LocalRequestInterceptor(23578): Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: Too many attempts.
E/FirebaseAuth(23578): [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17093 null```Also my daily limits are still not full so this shouldn't occur

Comment: One thing I have noticed here is that if I enter a real phone number in debug mode then it won't move ahead or OTP won't be sent but if I build the release version of the Flutter app and go through the same process then OTP will be sent meaning only way I could enter the app in debug mode is via test number only!

Comment: hmm. did you try `androidProvider:AndroidProvider.debug`  when you are using debug. maybe playIntegrity need release

Comment: @mageshmagi I am still facing the same issue even after adding the statement, phone number just don't get any OTP's even when I am release or debug mode, I will add my whole main.dart code above

Comment: `await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
    webRecaptchaSiteKey: _webKey,
    androidProvider: AndroidProvider.debug,
    appleProvider: AppleProvider.appAttest,
  );` remove this line and try. might be crazy. i try with out those line for me its working

`Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    name: 'taxi-111',//name from firebase
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}`. with this version `firebase_core: ^2.14.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.6.3`

Comment: @mageshmagi I have added my whole login page code for further reference, like even if I remove AppCheck I am still facing the same issue in both the build and debug app : / :(